# How to append context root in IBM HTTP Proxy for Liberty Server

Tags: java, proxy, websphere-liberty, application-server, contextroot

I have a Java EAR application deployed to a couple of liberty 16.x application servers, and have one IBM HTTP Proxy server (Apache) running in front of it acting as the load balancer and HTTPS proxy. I want to have our intranet users simply enter in an easy to remember URL like https://product-aa and then be redirected to https://server-aa:8443/EarApplication, without needing to have them manually add the context root in the URL.

I'm trying to figure out the best way to achieve this.

Comment: Are you using the WAS Plug-in or mod_proxy? Do you already use virtual hosts in IHS and if so, what is your apachectl -S output?

Comment: I'm using the WAS Plug-in (plugin-cfg.xml), and I'm not sure about the virtual host configuration in the httpd.conf as we're pretty much using the one that came with the IBM installation of the IHS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, register product-aa in DNS as a CNAME for server-aa

Then append to httpd.conf:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<virtualhost *:80>
  ServerName server-aa
</virtualhost>
<virtualhost *:80>
  ServerName product-aa
  RedirectMatch ^/$ /EarApplication
  # ... or http://server-aa/EarApplication
</virtualhost>
```